# Transform a surface into a 2D density plot

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot the solution of an equation in three dimensions $f(x,y,z)$ via a color/heat map in 2 dimensions where each point is assigned a color corresponding to the z value. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Probably. Give us an example of $f(x,y,z)$. Also, do you mean the solution to the equation $f(x,y,z)=0$?

Comment: Are you sure it makes sense? This is basically a `ContourPlot3D[ ... ==0]` which gives you a surface, but nothing ensures a priori that it has exactly one value in $z$. Then how to color more than two values in one pixel ? I mean $f(x,y,z)=0$ might not define a $g(x,y)=z$.

Comment: Your question makes no sense:  A function $f(x,y,z)$ means that you take as input a value of $x$, and $y$, and $z$ and give a *different* value as output.  It makes no sense to assign a color corresponding to the $z$ value.  You'd have to put a different color (such as a rainbow) for the different values of $z$ but it would have nothing whatsoever to do with some function $f(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret you as saying `f[x,y,z]==0` implicitly defines `z` as a function of `x` and `y`.

```
f = Function[{x, y, z}, z - Sqrt[x*y]]
eqs = Table[0 == f[x, y, i], {i, 3}]
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqs, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

[image: c]

If you prefer, you can use a similar approach to produce a density plot.

```
Table[z /. First@Solve[0 == f[x, y, z], z], {x, 5}, {y, 5}]
ListDensityPlot[%, PlotTheme -> "Default"]
```

[image]

Comment: Not a density plot...  color... heat map....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Added.